# How to resolve Error 80072F76 while updating windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Error 80072F76 while updating windows phone.
Reply Quote Edit
While updating windows phone 7 to 7.5 in zune i am getting the following error:

Can't check for updates right now. Please try again later. An Error has  occured
80072F76

Please tell me ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [MSDN Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941) suggests that the issue may be a firewall or antivirus stopping you from connecting properly. If you are trying this at work then you may need to contact your administrator to rectify this.

If both of these have been checked and disabled (for a very short time) or fixed then it may be a temporary issue with your ISP or even Microsoft. In that case I'd give it half an hour, then try the update again

Comment: Thanks it's firewall issue.we are able to do that..